# Realm Swift how to add observer to object type (nil)

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Assume i have two flows:

1) I have data in database, then i use fetch entity with params from database and set and observer. After that i load data from server and observer's block fires successfully. That's fine.

2) I don't have data in database. Then i try to do the same, it looks like:

```
    myObject = MyRealmService()
        .fetchAll(MyRealmObject.self,
                  filter: "userID == \(someID)")?
        .first
    realmToken = myObject?.observe { [weak self] change in
        guard let _self = self else { return }

        switch change {
        case .deleted:
            _self.popCurrentViewController()
        case .error(let error):
            _self.show(error: error)
        case .change:
            _self.updateUI()
        }
    }

    loadDataFromServer() { object in
         object.saveToRealm()
    }
```

Then myObject is nil, so the notification block don't setting.

What is the way to handle notifications in this way? I mean, maybe somehow we can set the block to the filter type (`MyRealmObject.self, filter: "userID == \(someID)"`), so if in realm has write the object that fits it, then the observe block fires?

Comment: You state *I don't have data in database*. So... why are you using a database if you're not storing any data in it? In that case it's just an object floating around in memory and you could leverage [KVO; Key Value Observing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/using_key-value_observing_in_swift) with (swift) *dynamic* keyword for the properties you want to observe. Or, if it's an NSObject, you can still use KVO. Are you asking how to observe an object that's only in memory and has not been stored to Realm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of observing individual object which is still not stored in Realm database, you could observe Realm [Results](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Results.html#/s:10RealmSwift7ResultsC7observeySo20RLMNotificationTokenCyAA0A16CollectionChangeOyACyxGGcF)

```
   let realm = try! Realm()

    var results = realm.objects(MyRealmObject.self).filter: "userID == \(someID)")

    var notificationToken = results.observe { change in
        switch change {
        case .update:
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                block()
            }
        default: ()
        }
    }
```

You can observe the result object instead of individual and do some action based on changes.